# Differential Equation $y'-1=\frac{y}{x}-\frac{y^2}{x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone help me solve this equation ??

I think it's Riccati equation but no answer is given in the question

$$y'-1=\frac{y}{x}-\frac{y^2}{x^2}$$

The answer must contain $y$ and $x$ and free of $y'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put $\frac{y}{x}=u$ so $$y=ux \to y'=u+u'x$$
$$y'-1=\frac{y}{x}-\frac{y^2}{x^2}\\u+u'x-1=u-u^2\\u'x=1-u^2\\\frac{du}{dx}x=1-u^2\\\frac{du}{1-u^2}=\frac{dx}{x}$$ now apply integral for both sides
$$\frac{1}{2} \ln{\frac{1-u}{1+u}}=\ln x +\ln c$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Plug in $y=vx$ and do the required transformations to get $$x\frac{dv}{dx}=1-v^2$$ You should now be able to solve this.